# Python merge second part of tuple list into list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I have only recently started learning Python, and I have looked at similar questions and cannot seem to find an example that helps - I have this list of tuples currently:

```
 [('E', ['E', 'F', 'C', 'C']), ('F', ['A', 'D', 'D', 'B']), ('I', ['F', 'D', 'F', 'D']), ('R', ['E', 'B', 'D', 'B']), ('S', ['B', 'C', 'C', 'D'])]
```

and I want to split them up into a list of strings, so that they look like this:

```
['EFCC', 'ADDB', 'FDFD', 'EBDB', 'BCCD']
```

I have tried to use the '.join' function for this, as shown below:

```
stringList = "".join([str(x[1]) for x in sortedList])
```

but this provides me with a list in the form:

```
['B', 'D', 'E', 'C']['B', 'C', 'B', 'D']['E', 'C', 'D', 'C']['B', 'C', 'D', 'C']['C', 'E', 'F', 'A']
```

I think I am using the join method wrong, but after changing a few bits about in it, I can't figure out how to get the format I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is `str(x[1])`.

`x[1]` is a list, and you convert it to a string:

```
>>> x = ('E', ['E', 'F', 'C', 'C'])
>>> x[1]
['E', 'F', 'C', 'C']

>>> str(x[1])
"['E', 'F', 'C', 'C']"
```

What you want is to join the elements of the list:

```
>>> ''.join(x[1])
'EFCC'
```

So your code would become:

```
[''.join(x[1]) for x in sortedList]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension and join the strings, like so.

```
t = [('E', ['E', 'F', 'C', 'C']), ('F', ['A', 'D', 'D', 'B']), ('I', ['F', 'D', 'F', 'D']), ('R', ['E', 'B', 'D', 'B']), ('S', ['B', 'C', 'C', 'D'])]

x = [''.join(b) for a, b in t]
print(x)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, could you please explain where the "for a,b in t" comes from? As I am getting the error "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)", and am not sure what to change to avoid expecting 2

Comment: Sure `t` is the list itself. `a` and `b` hold the values for the two elements of each tuple, `a` is a single character and `b` is the list. Try printing `[a for a, b in t]` or `[b for a, b in t]`. It is `b` we are interested in here.

Comment: `t` is a tuple with two elements. Paul is unpacking them into two variables `a` and `b`. Unpacking only works for sequences with the same amount of elements as variables, otherwise you get the error you're seeing. See the last paragraph of [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Comment: That error would imply your input data has some elements with one item in the tuple. Could this be the case?

Comment: In that case accessing the 2nd index of the tuple (i.e. x[1]), when not using unpacking, should bring about a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map:

```
print map(lambda x: "".join(x[1]),t)
```

Output:

```
['EFCC', 'ADDB', 'FDFD', 'EBDB', 'BCCD']
```

Comment: When printing the map, I am getting <map object at 0x000000767A840FD0>, how can I print this without just getting the address?

Comment: @user3379139: `list(map(lambda x: "".join(x[1]),t))`. You're using Python 3 and `map()` on Python 3 returns a `map` object instead of a list.

Comment: By the way, you can still use `map` object *as* a list anyways.